# Python - IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, file, io

I'm getting `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` and I don't know what is wrong wit this code.

I'm trying to read a file given an absolute path (meaning only `file.asm`),

and a relative path (meaning `/.../file.asm`), and I want the program to write the file to whatever path is given - if it is absolute, it should write it to the current dir; otherwise, to the path given.

the code:

```
#call to main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assem(sys.argv[1])


import sys

def assem(myFile):
    from myParser import Parser
    import code
    from symbolTable import SymbolTable

    table=SymbolTable()

    # max size of each word
    WORD_SIZE = 16
    # rom address to save to
    rom_addrs = 0
    # variable address to save to
    var_addrs = 16

    # new addition
    if (myFile[-4:] == ".asm"):
        newFile = myFile[:4]+".hack"

    output = open(newFile, 'w') <==== ERROR
```

the error given:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Use.hack'
```

the way I execute the code :

```
python assembler.py Users/***/Desktop/University/Add.asm
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: most probably you don'nt have prmissions to write to the root directory - and rightly so, it seems

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to replace the extension with the following code:

```
if (myFile[-4:] == ".asm"):
    newFile = myFile[:4]+".hack"
```

However, you appear to have the array indexes mixed up. Try the following:

```
if (myFile[-4:] == ".asm"):
    newFile = myFile[:-4]+".hack"
```

Note the use of `-4` instead of just `4` in the second line of code. This explains why your program is trying to create `/Use.hack`, which is the *first* four characters of your file name (`/Use`), with `.hack` appended to it.

Comment: yes, you are right. but now i get :
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/itzikhanoch/Desktop/University/Add.hack'

im using 'w' why should he find any file? it supposed to write it.

Comment: Now it looks like you are passing `User/...` instead of `/User/...`. Note the leading slash, that's important. Without the leading slash, you are trying to open a file in the *subdirectory of the current directory* called `User`.

Answer (score 44):

**Just Close the opened file where you are going to write.**

Comment: This answer makes no sense for the question…

Comment: This worked for me, what this person means is, if you have the folder you're trying to save into open, you need to close it

Answer (score 12):

You don't have sufficient permissions to write to the root directory.   See the leading slash on the filename?

Comment: is there anything that i can do about it? im writing this to a simple folder on my desktop, nothing special

Comment: Just try removing the '/' at the start.

Comment: Just what Len said. Remove the / at the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me when I was using 'shutil.copyfile' instead of 'shutil.copy'. The permissions were messed up.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. In my case, the user did not have write permission to the destination directory. Following command helped in my case :

```
chmod 777 University
```

Comment: This isn't giving the user write permissions, but giving everyone on your system *all* permissions; read, write and execute. I would recommend looking at user groups and permissions instead of opening up your folders like this!

Comment: Totally agreee. That’s the reason I mentioned “in my case” a couple times. It was the app on Ubuntu EC2 in AWS which needed permission 777 to a particular folder. Besides, the solution approach can be either taken starting from block-all or allow-all approach and then optimising; depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You are trying to open folder `with open`, check it once.

Comment: what do you mean by "check it once"

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing from above worked. So I solved my problem with this workaround.  Just check that you have added SYSTEM in directory folder. I hope it will help somoene.

```
import os
# create file
@staticmethod
def create_file(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.system('echo # > {}'.format(path))

# append lines to the file
split_text = text_file.split('\n')
    for st in split_text:
        os.system('echo {} >> {}'.format(st,path))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are implementing the code inside a could drive like box, dropbox etc. If you copy the files you are trying to implement to a local folder on your machine you should be able to get rid of the error.

Comment: Just wondering how this would impact it? I have this error, and the file is on a mounted Google Drive (Google Drive File Stream).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a permissions issue.

Use the 'Take Ownership' application on that specific folder. 
However, this sometimes seems to work only temporarily and is not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I had this permission error because the file that it was trying to create was already open/used by another program (was created last time the script was run, I had opened it with excel, and then got a permission error when it was trying to recreate it)

leaving this here in case someone else finds it useful, it is not the real solution to the question asked

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the directory didn't exist yet.

Solution: create the directory

```py
import os
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```