# Python - IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python

Im trying to get a local directory from argv and iterate through the folder and print the contents of each file within. However i am getting a [Errno] 13 saying permission denied. Ive tried researching the problem but have come up empty handed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys


path = open(sys.argv[1],'r')   #'inputs/' path to working input dir
file_list = os.listdir(path)    #create list of filenames in path dir
for fn in file_list:
    file = open(path+'/'+fn)        #open each file in dir for manipulation
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Have you read this yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575750/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: yes that post is about writing out. Im just trying to figure out why I dont have permission to read a file.

Comment: What is the value of `fn` when the error occurs? Is it a subdirectory of `path`?

Comment: I believe it errors out at file_list = os.listdidr(path)
path gets the value 'inputs' which is a local folder

Comment: You can't open a folder with `open()`.

Comment: open() works if i supply the string 'inputs' instead of getting it from argv

Answer (score 1):

[`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), as its name implies, returns a list of all occupants of the given directory, including both files and directories (and, if you're on Unix/Linux, other stuff like symlinks and devices and whatnot). You are then blindly trying to [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) each item in the list and `print()` its contents. Unfortunately, `open()` only works on file-like objects, and specifically does *not* work on directories, hence Errno 13, Permission Denied.

An alternative is to use [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), which works a little bit differently. Instead of returning a flat list that you can read immediately, `os.scandir()` returns a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) which essentially gives you objects as you ask for them, instead of giving them all to you at once. In fact, the following code adapted from the docs is a good starting place for what you need:

```
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file():
       print(entry.name)
```

`os.scandir()` is returning [`DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects. Simply use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create a full pathname out of the `path` argument you pass to `os.listdir()` in your original code, and `entry.name` from the code above, and then, using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) context manager, `open()` the file and display its contents:

```
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file():
       with open(os.path.join(path, entry), "r") as f:
           for line in f:
               print(line)
```

One of the advantages of using `with` is that you don't have to remember to close the file handle that is assigned when you use something like this:

```
f = open("myfile.txt, "r")
# do stuff with f
...
f.close()
```

Otherwise, you have a dangling file handle that *could* potentially cause problems, depending on how many there are and what you've done with them. It's just a good practice to `close()` what you `open()`. With `with`, you don't have to worry about it - the file handle is closed as soon as you exit the block.