# PermissionError: [Errno 13]: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem.

[Error log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNnnM.png)

How I can solve this, when I write: pip install -r requirements.txt

In my case in Python install ways, please help to understand. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `sudo`. Although the recommended way to install requirements for a project is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - IOError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575750/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

The errors suggest that the user you are trying to install the python module with, `aset`, does not have permission to write in the default python modules install path.
You may:

1. Use `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` to install as super user
2. Download the packages from the requirement file `requirements.txt` in your user's home directory, untar them and import them in your script.

You may use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///tmp/packages
```

to get all packages from your requirements file.

Original source for above command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-pip-install-packages-according-to-requirements-txt-from-a-local-directory)

To import python modules from a custom path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/module_directory')
from module_directory import module
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sudo to install the package in the system folder **(not recommended)**

```
sudo pip3.5 install 'the_package_name'
```

or you  can use --user option to install the package in the user folder

```
pip3.5 install 'the_package_name' --user
```