# Move a file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, movefile

I want to move a file and I'm having the following bug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Programming\Hack\scripts\# cut file.py", line 4, in <module>
shutil.move(src, dst)
File "C:\Program Files 1\Python2\lib\shutil.py", line 316, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
File "C:\Program Files 1\Python2\lib\shutil.py", line 144, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst)
File "C:\Program Files 1\Python2\lib\shutil.py", line 97, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\windows.information.exe'
```

my script:

```
import shutil
src = "C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\windows.information.exe"
dst = "E:\\"
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

My main problem:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\windows.information.exe
```

Comment: Try using shutil.copy() instead https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

Comment: If your file is an exe, try to close the program it runs before copying.

Comment: Possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575750/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - IOError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575750/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact，this error occurred by permission. in  c://Users ,need adminster authority
to do it . you should use shutil.copy(src,dst) copy file and authority

Answer (score 0):

The log shows you do not have proper permissions to access the file. try changing the permissions first

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [shutil.copy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy), since shutil move looks for a file and E: it's a directory and not a file.

```
import shutil
src = "C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\windows.information.exe"
dst = "E:\\"
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```