# How to create a file in c:/windows/system32 folder using python

Tags: python, permissions

When I run the following code I get an error named permission denied:

```
f=open('C:/Windows/System32/azm.txt','w')
f.write('+989193667998')
f.close()
```

Comment: r is for reading not for writing

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575750/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, use backslashes instead of slashes to specify file paths:

`f = open(r'c:\windows\system32\azm.txt', 'w')`

And since you're trying to write to a system directory, make sure you run your code as Administrator.

Comment: Which environment are you using? if it's IDLE, right click before opening and choose 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: IDLE in windows 8. When I right click there is no option as 'Run as Adiminstrator'

Comment: I run it as administrator and my problem was solved. Thanks