# Opening multiple json files inside a for loop

Tags: python, json

I have some code that saves a json file and prints it to screen. I am trying to find the best way to iterate through a directory of files, printing one file after another, but I am receiving an '[Errno 13] Permission Denied' error.

At present I am doing the following:

```
json_path = 'MYPATH'
json_files = [f for f in os.listdir(json_path) if f.endswith('.json')]

for jf in json_files:
    with open (os.path.join(json_path)) as my_jf:
        json_text = json.load(my_jf)
        print(json_text)
```

I have made sure that the folder in the path is not opened elsewhere, and I have access to it. If there is a simpler way to achieve this I would appreciate the input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575750/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied this could help you

Comment: make sure to close the file after saving it. Perhaps it wasn't close after save and you are opening it again for reading and printing to console.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really open the files, you are opening the path where the files are located.
You could try to change:

```
with open (os.path.join(json_files)) as my_jf:
```

Comment: This will just join together all of the filenames... I don't think that's going to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across an answer of sorts. If I create a list of the text files in the directory the json.load request seems to work:

```
my files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

for file in myfiles:
    with open(file) as json_file:
    jsonconvo = json.load(json_file)
    print(jsonconvo)
```

I'm unsure if I've necessarily overcome the the actual issue, but this seems like a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just forgot to actually include the file name in your `open()` statement:

```
with open(os.path.join(json_path, jf)) as my_jf:
```